# Does carpet of stars requires replanting?

Tags: lawn, succulents

I'm thinking to switch out my grass to Carpet of Stars (Ruschia Nana) but I read they last up to four years. Would like to know if I need to replant the carpet from scratch or do the seeds given out by the plant sustain itself with offspring. Curious if anyone has had a carpet of stars for more than four years and has already gone through this.

What is done with the ones that turn "woody"?

https://guide2agriculture.com/dwarf-carpet-of-stars/

https://gardeningit.com/dwarf-carpet-of-stars/